# Getting MalformedJsonException while generating google cloud endpoint client library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am getting following error in my eclipse while generating cloud endpoint client library for google app engine. I have tried restarting eclipse, cleaning my project. Nothing works. Any suggestions how to solve it?

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 711 column 10
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:769)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:721)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:670)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:642)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis.ManagedApiUtils.findAndReadDependencyFile(ManagedApiUtils.java:185)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis.ManagedApiUtils.findAndReadDependencyFile(ManagedApiUtils.java:179)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis.ManagedApiUtils.findAndReadDependencyFile(ManagedApiUtils.java:179)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.copyToConnectedAndroidProject(SwarmServiceCreator.java:148)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:453)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 711 column 10
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1298)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.objectValue(JsonReader.java:762)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:380)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.advance(JsonReader.java:426)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.skipValue(JsonReader.java:637)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:174)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the error by cleaning google app engine project after deleting these 3 autogenerated files for war/WEB-INF/ folders : *-rest.discovery, *-rpc.discovery, *.api